# How make assert not throw an error in python

Tags: python-3.x, assert

```
import os
def entrypoint():

flag.entrypoint()
assert(false)
```

What can I have in entrypoint function so that assert does not throw an error ? flag is file name.
been stuck on it for hours

Comment: What would be the point of `assert` if it didn't throw an error?  Maybe you need to go back and understand how to use it.

Comment: its for an exercise assignemnt

Comment: How do you normally catch errors? Assertion exceptions are the same

Answer (score 0):

Like any exception in python, if you want to catch it, [you have to use try-except block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). Like this:

```
>>> assert(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> try:
...     assert(False)
... except:
...     print("hello")
... 
hello
```

Comment: The thing is I cannot change anything other than the entrypoint()